# Can't connect to Sphinx (Full text search) from Docker application

Tags: php, laravel, sphinx

So I have a project running in a docker container like this:

```
$ docker-compose up -d nginx mysql redis workspace
```

Docker's running fine (all containers are up) 
and I'm now trying to integrate Sphinx Full Text Search into the workspace container.
I have the /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf file setup like this:

```
source tablename
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = mysql
    sql_user        = user
    sql_pass        = pass
    sql_db          = database_name
    sql_port        = 3306
    sql_query       = SELECT id, name FROM tablename
    sql_attr_uint   = id
}

index tablename
{
    source          = tablename
    path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/tablename
    min_prefix_len  = 2
    morphology      = stem_en
}

searchd
{
    listen              = 127.0.0.1:9312
    log                 = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
    query_log           = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
    query_log_format    = sphinxql
    pid_file            = /var/run/searchd.pid
}
```

and I've run the indexer as follows, which appears to be fine:

```
root@1ec9add2d1dc:/etc/sphinxsearch# /usr/bin/indexer tablename
Sphinx 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'tablename'...
WARNING: index 'tablename': dict=keywords and prefixes and morphology enabled, forcing index_exact_words=1
WARNING: attribute 'id' not found - IGNORING
WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo
collected 17 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 17 docs, 171 bytes
total 0.322 sec, 529 bytes/sec, 52.68 docs/sec
total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.3 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 9 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.2 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

and subsequent calls to /usr/bin/searchd -rotate are also patching the indexes.
I've also run searchd in the workspace container:

```
root@1ec9add2d1dc:/etc/sphinxsearch# /usr/bin/searchd 
Sphinx 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
listening on 127.0.0.1:9312
```

But I can't seem to connect to this from the application.
Sample code:

```
$query = 'keyword';
$sphinx = new SphinxClient();
$sphinx->setServer('127.0.0.1', 9312);
$sphinx->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
$sphinx->addQuery($query, 'tablename');
$sphinx->setLimits(0, 10);
$result = $sphinx->runQueries();
```

But $result is always false with the following error:

```
SPHINX Query failed: connection to 127.0.0.1:9312 failed (errno=111, msg=Connection refused)
bool(false)
```

Ive also tried changing the .conf and also the setServer() to use 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'mysql' (sql container name), but nothing actually connects to sphinx from the application code.

Question:
Am I missing something here? 
What other steps are required to connect to sphinx and retrieve actual index data?
Any help is much appreciated.

---

Running Docker Desktop on Mac OSX,
Ubuntu containers
PHP 7.2, "gigablah/sphinxphp": "^2.0.8", "laravel/framework": "^6.4.0",

Comment: Is the application running in the same container? Or a seperate container?

Comment: “trying to integrate Sphinx Full Text Search into the workspace container”.

Comment: Is the script working from outside if you run docker gigablah/sphinxphp and expose 9312? Also can you telnet to the port from inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

Given your docker-compose file is this:

```
....
sphinx:
  -p 9311:9312
....
```

Your sphinx.conf file should have this in your searchd

```
searchd {
  listen                    = 9312
  listen                    = 9306:mysql41
  .....
}
```

when connecting to sphinx with using PHP SphinxQL

```
$conn = new Connection();
$conn->setParams(array('host' => 'sphinx', 'port' => 9306));
$querybuilder = new SphinxQL($conn);
$querybuilder->insert()->into('rtidx')->set($records)->execute();
```